# How to play audio using JSON data from API call? (Spreaker)

Tags: javascript, json, html, audio, html5-audio

I'm trying to play an audio file from this json data.

https://api.spreaker.com/v2/episodes/5816235

```
  "episode":{  
     "episode_id":5816235,
     "type":"LIVE",
     "title":"SPR",
     "duration":null,
     "show_id":1341125,
     "author_id":7883468,
     "site_url":"https:\/\/www.spreaker.com\/episode\/5816235",
     }
```

Specifically, I'd like to scope into the episode_id, to play the live stream. As I am new to using API calls, what's the best way to use the data to play the audio? Is there a way to access it using Javascript?

Should I use something like Plyr? https://github.com/Selz/plyr

Comment: what's the url; of the media file you want to play? you can fetch the api with ajax/fetch, parse it, grab `response.episode.epsiode_id`, and add that onto a base url before setting the concated output as the .src of an <audio> tag.

Comment: The url is http://www.spreaker.com/user/spr-radio/spr_151

Answer (score 1):

I'm Marco, a Spreaker engineer. You can get the audio stream of any episode from the URL:

`https://api.spreaker.com/listen/episode/EPISODE-ID/http`

*(please replace `EPISODE-ID` with the ID of the episode you wanna play)*

You can then use that URL to play the episode in basically any player, including the `<audio>` tag on modern browsers.

#### Why Spreaker doesn't have an SDK?

We're currently in the process of finalizing and releasing a javascript SDK that will ease playing a Spreaker episode on web. Once ready, it will be published at https://developers.spreaker.com

Comment: Marco, I work at a Podcasting company and we have several shows on Spreaker. I've been trying to get the data to automatically pull to a database through your JSON and developer section but am having trouble. I've tried your help emails, but could really use more help. Is there a way you could help me with this?